# Get contents from one sharepoint list to another sharepoint list ,the source list has sinlge line text,multiline text (rich html),date columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I'm having a SharePoint list with 300 items, now just want the same list with same content (list template is not working). So I decided to recreate the list.

How to migrate the list items? Which is the easiest way to do this? PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate data from Lists using:

- Write C# console app to get data from one list and store it on another
- Use **Internet Explorer** and open those lists in **quick edit mode**, you can copy data (from IE you can select multiple rows and columns in list) from 1st list and paste it in 2nd list in quick edit mode.